# How to get local source port from socket connect() in Linux Kernel Space?

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel, port

I am manipulating the connect() function in Linux Kernel source code (net/socket.c file) and need to get the source and destination port of an established connection. The function takes a `struct sockaddr __user* uservaddr` parameter from which I already could get the destination port by casting it to a `struct sockaddr_in`. But where is the local source port stored? The function also declares a `struct socket* sock`, which possibly contains the data I need, but I couldn't find any variable with the source port. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
struct inet_sock *inet;
struct sock *sk = sock->sk;
inet = inet_sk(sk);
u16 post = ntohs(inet->inet_sport);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: source and dest ports can be found in struct inet_sock. You can access it from connect using:

```
inet = inet_sk(sock->sock)
```

**More details**:
The operations allowed on sockets are defined in struct proto_ops. By following the implementation for the connect() function for TCP (in net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c), you can see it is implemented by tcp_v4_connect():

```
int tcp_v4_connect(struct sock *sk, struct sockaddr *uaddr, int addr_len)
{
        struct sockaddr_in *usin = (struct sockaddr_in *)uaddr;
        struct inet_sock *inet = inet_sk(sk);
```

and later:

```
struct proto tcp_prot = {
        ...
        .connect                = tcp_v4_connect,
```

inet->inet_sport and inet->inet_dport are used for setting/getting source and destination ports in the function above.

From a quick look I can see inet_sock is already used in socket.c, so you don't need to include any additional header files.

Hope this helps.